# Fourier Mukai kernel which gives an equivalence only in one direction

Tags: derived-categories, derived-functors

If $X$ and $Y$ are two schemes and $F \in Perf(X \times Y)$, then we can define a functor from $Perf(X)$ to $Perf(Y)$ as the Fourier Mukai transform $\Phi^{X \rightarrow Y} = q_{\ast}(F \otimes p^{\ast}-)$, where $p$ and $q$ are the projections from $X \times Y$ to $X$ and $Y$ respectively. If $X$ and $Y$ are smooth we can change $Perf(-)$ to $D^b(-)$, while if choose $F$ only to be a complex with quasi coherent cohomologies we change $Perf(-)$ to $D_{qc}(-)$, the unbounded derived category of complexes with quasi coherent cohomologies. Obviously, we could exchange the role of $p$ and $q$ and get a functor from $Y$ to $X$. My question is whether the fact that $\Phi^{X \rightarrow Y}$ is an equivalence implies that $\Phi^{Y \rightarrow X}$ is an equivalence, and if it doesn’t I would like a counter example.

The reason why I believe it not might be the case that the implication holds is that there is no apparent relation between the two functors I described above, even though they share the same kernel. However, I was not able to come up with a counterexample.